# GraphQL query in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphql

I am using a sample API online from here: https://api.spacex.land/graphql/. I am using GraphQL in Unity to query the data for "Users". I am able to create a query and receive all properties such as ID, Name, etc. Unfortunately I cannot receive the details of these properties at all. Both the functions given below throw an error `Unknown argument`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
using GraphQlClient.Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GetStationDetails : MonoBehaviour {
    public GraphApi spacexGraph;
    public string Name = "Prakash";

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D)) {
            GetEnteredDetails ();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.F)) {
            GetAllDetails ();
        }
    }

    public async void GetEnteredDetails () {
        GraphApi.Query query = spacexGraph.GetQueryByName ("GetAllData", GraphApi.Query.Type.Query);
        query.SetArgs (new { name = Name });
        UnityWebRequest request = await spacexGraph.Post (query);
        Debug.Log ("Received: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
    }

    public async void GetAllDetails () {
        GraphApi.Query query = spacexGraph.GetQueryByName ("GetAllData", GraphApi.Query.Type.Query);
        query.SetArgs (new { first = 6 });
        UnityWebRequest request = await spacexGraph.Post (query);
        Debug.Log ("Received: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

[GraphQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvfKf.png)

[SpaceX_JSONapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2v7m.png)

Comment: Can you change your GetAllData query to : `query GetAllData {
  users(where: {name: {_in: "Prakash"}}) {
    id
    name
  }}` ? If I enter the one you used I also get an unknown argument error, since the query : `users(name: "XXX")` isn't supported. Instead spaceX uses `users(where: {name: {_in: "XXX"}})`

Comment: @TheBv Thank you i think that is the issue. Can I change it in code? As in ```query.SetArgs (new { where: {name:....}``` How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the query you tried to build wasn't correct.
Instead of using :

```
query.SetArgs (new { name = Name });
```

You want to use

```
query.SetArgs (new { where = new {name = new{_in = Name}} });
```

This should create the Query:

```
query GetAllData{
    users(where:{name:{_in: "Parkash"}}){
        id 
        name
        rocket
        timestamp
    }
}
You can also change _in to e.g "_like", if you want to get any name that partly matches what you've entered, or any other similar SQL keyword
```